# how to compare two values and keep the lowest one

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to find a way to keep the lowest value from a series of comparisons inside of a variable in python.

something like

```
"if newvalue is lower than storagevalue then storagevalue now is newvalue"
```

and so on.

I thought to just stuff all them inside a list and then to keep the lowest, but it have to be done inside of a process which could become really memory-taking so I wanted to find a less "hungry" solution, avoiding to keep a lot of really big numbers.

The problem I see is that I don't know how to manage the storagevalue in the first place. I cannot just declare it as an empty variable and then compare it with a new value; neither I can assign a dummy value as 'x' in the meantime, it doesn't work.

maybe I'm just thinking the wrong way, I'm just starting to learn Python,

thanks

Comment: Where are the numbers coming from, a database, a text file? The typical way to do this is to declare a value and set it to the max value of an integer and then if you encounter a value lower, set the variable to that new value

Comment: the numbers are coming from an eurhistic algorithm

Comment: Thanks everybody: I finally ended up assigning an initializing boolean variable `"first = True"` : every round it checks if this variable is true, if it is, it writes directly in the storage AND puts it in false state, if it is not, it compares as normal.

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `storagevalue` to something. Usually you use the first `newvalue`.

```
storagevalue = min(storagevalue, newvalue)
```

Alternatively, if your values are already in a list you can just use `min` directly.

```
storagevalue = min(newvaluelist)
```

Since you still seem to not understand, just try this:

```
first = True
while newvalue_available:
    if first:
        storagevalue = newvalue
        first = False
    else:
        storagevalue = min(newvalue, storagevalue)
    # read newvalue here
```

Comment: unfortunately I cannot initialize storage thath way.  `storagevalue = min(storagevalue, 982394290192)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#59>", line 1, in <module>
    storagevalue = min(storagevalue, 982394290192)
NameError: name 'storagevalue' is not defined'`

Comment: You can't reference `storagevalue` when you initialize it. Simply assign a value to it `storagevalue = 982394290192)`.

Comment: That's why I said to initialize with the *first* value.

Answer (score 0):

Start the `storagevalue` with the maximum value an int can take.

```
import sys
storagevalue = sys.maxsize
```

And then,

```
storagevalue = min(storagevalue, newvalue)
```

Comment: In python 3 there’s no `sys.maxint`, but you could do `storagevalue = sys.maxsize` instead. See https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers

Comment: sys.maxsize return value `2147483647`... which is not that big actually.